# SQL reserved word in an $array resulting in Error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I'm having a problem when I try to insert an array that has a reserved word on it.

It's really wierd I might say, take a look:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO sites (cat_id, cat_title, cat_parent, title, image, site_name, description) VALUES ('$_POST[cat_id]','$_POST[cat_title]','$_POST[cat_parent]','$title','$image','$site_name','$description')";
```

The array is comming from a opengraph fetch that I created but it's not important, the question is that sometimes when the array $title, for example, or $image has a reserved word like "use" on it, the sql return the error "Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds...."

so that's the case:

when the array $title = http://techcrunch.com/2012/08/28/flipboard-hits-20-million-users-3-billion-flips-per-month/ <---- it don't work and I receive the error above.

when the array is $title = http://techcrunch.com/2012/08/27/google-nexus-7-is-now-available-in-france-germany-and-spain/ <---- it works fine!

so I think that probably because theres a 'reserved word' in the array $title sometimes (or any other array that I'm using) that is returning the error... So theres any way that I could protect my arrays from this error?

Thanks! :)

---

EDIT:

SOLUTION

Ok! I followed the @dystroy and @tadman advice and used PDO instead of the regular mysql connection... I don't know if I'm totally secure against SQL injetion or attacks but it solve my problem with the reserved words. Now I can insert whatever content I have in an $array to the database.

If someone end up here with the same problem, that's what I did (please complain if you guys find any awkwardness):

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=MYHOST;dbname=MYDATABASE", "USER", "PASS");

$query = "INSERT INTO sites (cat_id, cat_title, cat_parent, title, image, site_name, description) VALUES (:cat_idpost, :cat_titlepost, :cat_parentpost, :titlepost, :imagepost, :site_namepost, :descriptionpost)";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

$stmt->bindParam(':cat_idpost', $cat_id);
$stmt->bindParam(':cat_titlepost', $cat_title);
$stmt->bindParam(':cat_parentpost', $cat_parent);
$stmt->bindParam(':titlepost', $titlepost);
$stmt->bindParam(':imagepost', $imagepost);
$stmt->bindParam(':site_namepost', $site_namepost);
$stmt->bindParam(':descriptionpost', $descriptionpost);

$cat_id = $_POST['cat_id'];
$cat_title = $_POST['cat_title'];
$cat_parent = $_POST['cat_parent'];
$titlepost = $title;
$imagepost = $image;
$site_namepost = $site_name;
$descriptionpost = $description;
$stmt->execute();
```

Thank you guys! :D

Comment: can try backtics(`) for the column that may have reserve words

Comment: Unless you have some compelling reason to be writing this kind of stuff by hand, you would be better off using a framework like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) or [CodeIgnighter](http://codeignighter.com/) to provide a foundation to build off of. Writing SQL of this sort today is like making your own tires for your car, time consuming and potentially very dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use prepared statement to insert strings in a database. Never simply concatenate them.

The problem isn't only reserverd words but all kind of errors (or attacks) due to special values or characters. Don't try to escape all this yourself : The database will handle that for you if you use a prepared statement.

Look at those samples based on today's recommended library for PHP/MySQL ([PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)) : http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Absolutely. The original question is a sterling example of precisely what not to do. That kind of code can get you fired or can destroy your business, it is not an academic concern. PDO or `mysqli` are the way to go. Using placeholders is **NOT** optional. It cannot be emphasized enough how important it is to let the database driver escape **ANY** and **ALL** data being inserted. If, as a developer, you don't know how to do this, before you do anything else, your next order of business is to learn how.

Answer (score -1):

Escape reserved words like title with accents

Comment: That's not the problem. That's like putting a bandage on someone suffering from a heart-attack.